# Why this method creates one last empty row on csv file?

Tags: java, mysql, csv, javafx

I have this java method to create a csv file based on a mysql database. The file is created correctly but the problem is that in the end of the table an empty row it's added. I've tried to avoid this including an if else sentence but I've couldn't fix it. Help!

In fact I'm working with javafx, but it's a java error so...

This is the method code fixed(the problem apparently is due to phpmyadmin when I try to import the csv file adds an empty row at the end):

```
public void csv(String tabla) throws IOException{
    try{
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss");
        java.util.Date fecha=new java.util.Date();
        String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        String filename= workingDir + "/" + dateFormat.format(fecha) + ".csv";
        File file= new File(filename);
        FileWriter writer=new FileWriter(file);
        writer.append("fecha");
        writer.append(',');
        writer.append("hora");
        writer.append(',');
        writer.append("fechatotal");
        writer.append(',');
        writer.append("temperatura");
        writer.append(',');
        writer.append("humedad");
        writer.append(',');
        writer.append("luminosidad");
        ResultSet resultado = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM "+tabla+" ORDER BY fechatotal DESC");
        while(resultado.next()){
            writer.append('\n');
            writer.append(resultado.getDate("fecha").toString());
            writer.append(',');
            writer.append(resultado.getTime("hora").toString());
            writer.append(',');
            writer.append(resultado.getTimestamp("fechatotal").toString());
            writer.append(',');
            writer.append( Double.toString(resultado.getDouble("temperatura")));
            writer.append(',');
            writer.append(Double.toString(resultado.getDouble("humedad")));
            writer.append(',');
            writer.append(Double.toString(resultado.getDouble("luminosidad")));
        }
            writer.close();
        }catch(SQLException e){  
            e.printStackTrace();
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setHeaderText("Error(CSV)");
        alert.setContentText("Uuuuups, ha ocurrido un error!");
        alert.showAndWait();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @khelwood I've just gone through and improved it a bit...

Comment: Indentation is the thing that someone has edited your question and fixed.

Comment: You can use the [`isLast()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#isLast()) method instead of going forward then back, it might make your code more readable

Comment: I've edited the code, making it more readable, but it is still creating the last empty row, maybe it is for the last writer.append? @Bibz

Comment: You just *totally* changed the code. There's no way to get a blank line with the new code.

Comment: Apparently my code is good and it works, i've open the csv file with google drive and it shows the correct rows, but when I import it to phpmyadmin database it adds an last empty row, so the problem it is not the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**!! This answer is for the code in the original question !!**

Please don't do that `next()` / `previous()` combination. Very bad pattern. For example, you're outputting the `luminosidad` value of the *next* row, except for the last row.

You're already in the right path with the header row, by not appending the newline when the header row is built. Continue that pattern with the data rows, in which case *all* data rows must *start* with a newline.

**Note:** Since you're not buffering your writer, string concatenation is much better. And the code is much easier to read too.

```
String sql = "SELECT *" +
              " FROM " + tabla +
          " ORDER BY fechatotal DESC";
try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file)) {
    writer.write("fecha" +
                ",hora" +
                ",fechatotal" +
                ",temperatura" +
                ",humedad" +
                ",luminosidad");
    try (ResultSet resultado = st.executeQuery(sql)) {
        writer.write("\n" + resultado.getDate("fecha") +
                      "," + resultado.getTime("hora") +
                      "," + resultado.getTimestamp("fechatotal") +
                      "," + resultado.getDouble("temperatura") +
                      "," + resultado.getDouble("humedad") +
                      "," + resultado.getDouble("luminosidad"));
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right with previous() and next() pattern, it was only for testing. But unfortunately your code still adds an empty row at the end :(

Comment: How does it add an extra row??? The *only* newline being written are immediately followed by text (the `fecha` date), so there **simply cannot** be any blank lines.

Comment: EDIT:Apparently your code was good and it works, i've open the csv file with google drive and it shows the correct rows, but when I import it to phpmyadmin database it adds an last empty row, so the problem it is not the code. Thanks anyway I will use your shorter and not-hurt-for-eyes code :)

Answer (score 0):

Because if the code in this condition is hit on your last line, it leaves a hanging new_line.

```
if(resultado.next()){
    writer.append(Double.toString(resultado.getDouble("luminosidad")));
    writer.append('\n'); //appends a blank row when hit
}
```